# IntBuffer to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage

I have a class that looks like:

```
class Game {
   private IntBuffer GameBuffer = null;

   public Game(int Width, int Height) {
       GameBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Width * Height * 4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
   }


   public BufferedImage getGameBuffer() {
        return this.GameBuffer;  //Need to return my GameBuffer without making a copy.
    }
}
```

How can I return my GameBuffer such that it is a BufferedImage but not a copy of the GameBuffer.

In other words, when I call:

```
Canvas.draw(GameInstance.getGameBuffer()); //Uses Graphics g.drawImage(...);
```

It would draw on my GameBuffer, not a copy. How can I achieve this? I need to use the Int/Byte-Buffer because I need it for my JNI functions.

Comment: What does the IntBuffer actually contain?

Comment: Well the game works like this.. There are three modes: Safe-Mode, OpenGL, DirectX. In Safemode, it draws directly on a Canvas and that canvas draws directly on the bufferedimage. In the OGL and DX modes, it gets the Imaging from a DLL instead which uses the IntBuffer.

I didn't want to have to create both a BufferedImage and IntBuffer so I'm wondering if there is a way to have the canvas draw on the IntBuffer or if I can link them both such that the backing for both the intbuffer and bufferedimage would be the same. I want to do this s that it uses the same buffer regardless of modes.

Comment: `Graphics` doesn't know anything about `IntBuffer` or how it should be rendered.  You're going to have create a `BufferedImage` and set the `WritableRaster`'s pixels directly and translate back and forwards

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).